# Rails: When does methods mentioned in first line of the ControllerClass get executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I come across methods calls, written in the ControllerClass Scope, something like (in [here](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/issues/437#issuecomment-23948249)):

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  # Is this a before_action or after_action or just an alias or something else?
  pagination_header :index                    # <----- when will this be called

  def index
  # some logic here
  end

end
```

When exactly are they executed, and how exactly are they internally bound *(are they callbacks attached to somewhere)* ?

---

**EDIT**: I got to know that `pagination_header` is  a method that should execute just before the render method inside `index`. How is it possible to construct such a method?

This is possible perhaps by including `after_action` inside `pagination_header` method, but how is it called just before render action, if its just a method call that would be executed only once when the class gets loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses the ActiveDispatch::Callbacks middleware to make sure that callbacks are run. This is a Rack compatible middleware which means it can be added anywhere in the middleware chain. When a request hits Rails, it decides which controller action is going to serve the request and it basically wraps the controller action between before and after callbacks.

As long as middleware implement Rack's interface, you can call them in whichever order you like. So, I guess `before_action` callbacks are run calling Rack interface's "call" method, then the action doing the same and finally `after_action` callbacks are executed. The response gets augmented (or not) along the way. Some headers might be added, something changing in the response body, or nothing at all, such as logging.

If you want to learn more about how callbacks manage to get wrapped, you should check out [ActiveSupport::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html), although it's quite easy to roll your own.

```
class ARailsController
  def self.after_action(callback)
    @@after_callbacks ||= []
    @@after_callbacks << callback
  end

  def execute_callbacks
    @@after_callbacks.each { |callback| callback.call() }
  end
end

class MyController < ARailsController
  after_action Proc.new { puts "This will be executed afterwards" }
  after_action Proc.new { puts "Save this for later" }
end

controller = MyController.new
controller.execute_callbacks
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking at is just a class method. There is no Controller Scope, but I understand what your instinct is telling you.

In Ruby there are many "scope gates", like the `class` keyword, the `def` keyword, the `module` keyword. Every time you pass a scope gate, the implicit receiver of messages changes. The implicit receiver is the object referenced by the keyword `self`. Remember, that all methods in Ruby are messages, passed to either an explicit or implicit receiver. Explicit receivers can easily be identified by the dot notation (`receiver.method`).

Every time you encounter a line of code in Ruby you should ask yourself: "who is self right now?". If you answer this question you'll know where to look for the method definition.

In your example, there is a scope started by the `class` keyword (`class MoviesController`). This means that the implicit receiver (or self) is the class itself. Try this

```
class MyClass
  self #=> MyClass
end
```

A good beginner's tutorial that I could find is [this post](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/). If you want to dive deeper into the Ruby object model, I recommend the book Metaprogramming Ruby by P. Perotta.

Comment: I totally understand that `self` _(which is Ruby's equivalent of `this`)_ refers to **enclosed scope**, but unfortunately that isn't my question!

Comment: I believe _(from the [context](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/issues/437#issuecomment-23948249))_ `pagination_header :index` would get executed everytime the def `index` is called, tyring to find more about how and when **Rails** calls the line `pagination_header :index` line

Comment: The method is going to be executed whenever the class is loaded. You've just called a class method on the class object. That's what I was trying to explain above, about receivers. In Ruby every class is an object, so the method is called when Ruby gets a MovieController class, which is when the class is loaded. I hope it's now clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Every thing in rails is an object or methods associated with those objects.

Let us take an example, as you asked about `before_action` or `after_action`

**Let us take a rails **`model`** first:**

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :record_signup

  private
    def record_signup
      self.signed_up_on = Date.today
    end
end
```

Many of the inbuilt functions that are present in rails will be from **`ActiveRecord::Base`**, which inturn a class of
**`ActiveRecord module`**.

so all the methods that we use in the model will be from this class.

Eg:

`before_create` in the above is from class `ActiveRecord::Callbacks` and the file is
`activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb`

[Active record Callbascks](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

Eg:

`validates :name, presence: true` in the above is from class `ActiveRecord::Validations` and the file is

[Active record Validations](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html)

In the same way remaining methods such as `assosciations`, `timezones`, `attributes`, `enums` and many from the same module.

[Active record class main URL](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord.html)

**The same applies for controller,**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.create params[:post]
    redirect_to posts_path
  end
end
```

The application controller inherits from  `ActionController::Base`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login
 
  private
 
  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
      redirect_to new_login_url # halts request cycle
    end
  end
end
```

Many of the inbuilt functions that are present in rails will be from **`ActionController::Base`**, which inturn a class of
**`ActionController module`**.

so all the methods that we use in the model will be from this class.

[Action controller](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController.html)

-------**Note:**--------

**The execute line by line from top to bottom.**

`before_action` is calling of method so, it is called directly.

```
def index
end
```

The above is the definition but we are not calling this, so this won't gets executed until we call it through a route.

Comment: so before_action attaches callbacks to _userWritten_ methods' render method? ok, :D callbefores?

Comment: sry, didn't get you, pelase elaborate

Comment: `before_action :require_login`, this line means, we are calling that method, so that method will search for its actual definition, and will find from some of the class which was inherited and will run.

Comment: yes, talking about what before_action would do! `will run` <-- `run what?`: attaches callbefores to userWritten methods' render method?

Comment: it will run the definition of that method before our  render methods, for example, the `before_action` is a method and it has definition. check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action